# The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Pls help me how to fixed it

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have some codes like this:

```
 public int GetCount()
    {
        // Get the count of each item in the cart and sum them up
        var s = BikesDB.ShoppingCartItems.Where(cart => cart.ShoppingCartID == ShoppingCartID1).Select(cart => cart.Quantity).Sum(cart => cart);

        // Return 0 if all entries are null
        return s;
    }
```

And here what I got when I was debugging:

```
The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

I'm very appreciate any questions from yours, thank you so much!

Comment: try removing the sum part and see if it works,  guessing that one of those items is null and trying to sum it is trying to convert to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before doing the `Sum`, add `DefaultIfEmpty(0)` to the chain:

```
var s = BikesDB.ShoppingCartItems
               .Where(cart => cart.ShoppingCartID == ShoppingCartID1)
               .Select(cart => cart.Quantity)
               .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
               .Sum(cart => cart);
```

It will handle the case when you have no elements.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to throw in a Where call to filter out the items where Quantity is null, i.e.

```
var s = BikesDB.ShoppingCartItems.Where(cart => cart.ShoppingCartID == ShoppingCartID1 && cart.Quantity.HasValue).Sum(cart => cart.Quantity.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who are getting the error (probably because you are using a join):

**"does not contain a definition for 'DefaultIfEmpty'"**

```
var s = BikesDB.ShoppingCartItems
               .Where(cart => cart.ShoppingCartID == ShoppingCartID1)
               .Select(cart => cart.Quantity)
               .Sum(cart => cart)
               .GetValueOrDefault(0);
```

In my case I needed it because of this join:

```
return  Orders
    .Join(
    OrderLogisticss,
    o => o.ID,
    ol => ol.OrderID,
    (o, ol) => new { Order = o, OrderLogistics = ol })
    .Where(x => x.OrderLogistics.DepartureDate == date)
    .Sum(x => x.Order.NumberOfCarts)
    .GetValueOrDefault(0);
```